# Partial Differential/Integration Arbitrary Functions

Tags: partial-derivative

Use integration to find a solution involving one or more arbitrary functions
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$

for a function $u(x,y,z)$
$$u(x,y,z)=x\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$

let $y=\sinh v$
$$u(x,y,z)=x\int \frac{\cosh v\: dv}{\sqrt{1+\sinh ^2v}}$$

$$u(x,y,z)=x\sinh^{−1}(y)+f(x,z)$$

So here's the question. Why is the solution with an arbirary function $f(x,z)$ and not two arbitrary functions $f(x)+g(z)$? What's the difference?
I understand if the arbitrary function was something like $f(x,z)=x^z$ then it couldn't be expressed in the form $f(x)+g(z)$. But we don't know what form the arbitrary function will be in, so the more general form $f(x,z)$ will serve better. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is even broader than two functions of one variable. Indeed, for any two functions $f$ and $g$, you have a function $F(x,z)=f(x)+g(z)$ and one solution $u$ that fits this function $F$.

On top of that, you also have functions $u$ that solve the equation and for which $F(x,z)$ cannot be expressed as $f(x)+g(z)$, for example the function $F(x,z)=z^x$ or $F(x,z)=xz$ or anything else you can think of.

EDIT: Your conclusion is slighly vague. You say that the general form $f(x,z)$ will serve better. That is not true, it's not that it will serve better, it is that the form serves while the form $f(x)+g(z)$ will *not* serve. You cannot express $f(x,z)=xz$ as $f(x)+g(z)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: So the $f(x,z)$ case will serve all possibilities. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Because the "all" posibilities you must cover is "all functions of $x,y$ and $z$ which are constant in $y$."

Comment: Great. Thanks for helping get clear with this. Cheers

Comment: Happy to help. Consider accepting the question to let the others know it is what you need.